# Wordpress.com REST API "That API call is not allowed for this account."

Tags: php, wordpress, api, cakephp

I'm trying to include my free wordpress.com blog on my personal website using CakePHP. Displaying all the posts and accessing to each post on my website works fine but I can't post a comment. I'm getting :

> [
>       'error' => 'unauthorized',
>       'message' => 'That API call is not allowed for this account.'
>   ]

every time I submit a comment and I'm wondering why?

Comment: I've read on Wordpress that : "If everything works correctly and the user grants authorization, you will get back a JSON-encoded string containing the token and some basic information about the blog" but I'm getting blog_id => '0' and blog_url => null :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use the authorize url instead of the authenticate url.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found it. Here is details where to change.

```
$url_to = AUTHENTICATE_URL .'?'. http_build_query( $params );
```

I have changed AUTHENTICATE_URL with Authorize_URL and it works for me.

```
$url_to = Authorize_URL .'?'. http_build_query( $params );
```